# Email input field width changes only with inline style

Tags: html, css

I have an email input field which was set to 80% width in an inline style.  I moved the width parameter to a class with width: 80% but now the width shows 100%.

The html:

```
<div class="center_text_grid mktg_text">
<input type="text" class="joinpage_input" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" font-size: 18px;" required></div>
```

The css:

```
.center_text_grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 4 / 15;
    grid-row: 20 / 20;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 0%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center; }

.mktg_text{
    font-family: roboto_thinregular;
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: rgb(117,163,126);
    line-height: 1.5; }

.joinpage_input{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 45px;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: robotoregular;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    letter-spacing: 2px; }

::placeholder {
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    font-family: camphorW01-Thin,calibri,arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Why doesn’t the width: 80%; govern when it’s the class on the button and the other two classes have no width parameters?  Why does it work as an inline style and not as a class style?

Answer (score 0):

Code could look something like this:

```css
.joinpage_input {
  width: 80%;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px ridge rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="email_field" name="email_field" class="joinpage_input" type="email" placeholder="Your email address" autofocus required>
</div>
```